# DataBindingSource filter with combobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have dgv
[image]

Need to filter it when i choose specific value in combobox. If i chose Monday it should filter it by "Sort"

I tried with this code

```
   Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.TableDaysBindingSource.Filter = "Sort = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'"
End Sub
```

The result is empty table. What im i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah its `.Text` not the `.SelectedItem`

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.TableDaysBindingSource.Filter = "Sort = '" & ComboBox1.Text& "'"
End Sub
```